# How to refer to pages inside WEB INF using a:href

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have all my jsp pages inside webapp/WEB-INF/jsp. So I cannot access these pages from `a:href`. Pls tell me some way to make these `a:href` working

menu.jsp

```
<a:href=”mainmenu/Menu1.jsp”>
```

Menu1.jsp page is located in webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/mainmenu/Menu1.jsp

My spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bankofny.inx.omx.lc.web" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="resources.application" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class ClsSaveAction implements OMXServiceIDs {
@RequestMapping(value = "/ClsSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView execute(HttpServletRequest  request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response,
                                 @ModelAttribute("clsData") ClauseData clauseData,
                                 BindingResult bindingResult,
                                 Model model)
        throws Exception {

        System.out.println("inside this method");
        model.addAttribute("clsData", new ClauseData());

        try
        {
          .
.
.
.
.
.

            return new ModelAndView("blank", "clsData", new ClauseData());


        }

        catch (Exception e) {

          throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your spring configuration file along with controller.

Comment: you need a controller with request mapping having value "Menu1" as mentioned in answer. Please create a fresh new Hello project using given tutorial.

Comment: @Braj that example does not contain any links in href. My question is, how to make pages refer to location inside WEB INF? Anyway, I tried that link, which is your suggestion also. But dint work. I am not logically getting the flow. If i give `<a:href="menu1.jsp">`, will it get mapped to a handler?

Comment: Have you created a controller having "RequestMapping" with value "menu1"? Read the comments carefully.

Comment: **Steps:** Client (jsp) -> Request goes to Controller -> Controller includes page from WEB-INF and forward the request -> Client sees jsp response.

Comment: @Braj I gave this is my controller. But still not working. `@RequestMapping(value = "mainmenu/Menu1.jsp",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView returnPage(ModelMap model) {
        return new ModelAndView("mainmenu/Menu1.jsp");  
    }` I feel that my jsp page is not mapping properly with my controller. How to ensure that this jsp page goes to controller for this request mapping and returns the correct value?

Comment: can you debug the code? Or look into firebug under firefox for all network calls. You have to read more about "RequestMapping" and controllers. I suggest you to create a fresh sample "Hello World" project then move to next step.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Pages inside `WEB-INF` cannot be loaded by external programs, e.g. browsers.

Put it somewhere else.

Comment: It's in the context of spring-mvc and that is possible with some front controller servlet.

Comment: while using spring-mvc.. you have to put your views/pages in `web-inf`.. and to access them through link.. you have to use `<c:url>` tag.. "Put it somewhere else" is not an answer..

Comment: @Braj That would be contrary to the Servlet Specification #10.5.